# How to change search url without delete "s=" in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

As title, I want to change current url :

```
example.com/?s=foo
```

To :

```
example.com/search?s=foo
```

and if "s=" is not set, show all posts without any terms and filters.

---

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this:

```
wp_redirect(add_query_arg('s', $_GET['s'], home_url("search")));
```

instead of

```
 wp_redirect(home_url("/search/").add_query_arg('s', $_GET['s']));
```

Please have a look in the documentation of [home_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/) and [add_query_arg](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/).

Comment: How does the generated URL look like? Please output the result of `add_query_arg('s', $_GET['s'], home_url("search"))`. Maybe there is a slash missing.

Comment: Both, with slash and without slash I get error. output without slash : `example.com/search?s=foo` and with slash: `example.com/search/?s=foo`